# returning the top three results in google ajax

Tags: python, ajax, json

i am able, through the google ajax url, to get the first link from a page using this code.

```
def google(x):
    search = x.split()
    search = '%20'.join(map(str, search))
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=1&q=%s&safe=off' % search
    search_results = urlreq.urlopen(url)
    js = json.loads(search_results.read().decode())
    results = js['responseData']['results']
    for i in results: rest = i['unescapedUrl']
    return rest
```

What I would like to be able to do is to get the top three or four links using this same manner in an efficient way. I can return the top three links if i make three different searches using three different pages, but, that is rather inefficient. so to say again, I am using python 3.3 and I would like to be able to return the top three results. Using my method and not that of xgoogle.

Comment: i meant to say inefficient

Comment: You can just do: `search = '%20'.join(x.split())` or `search = urllib.parse.quote(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You are only returning the very last result in the response:

Change:

```
for i in results: rest = i['unescapedUrl']
```

To:

```
rest = [result['unescapedUrl'] for result in results]
```

Or:

```
urls = []
for result in results:
   urls.append(result['unescapedUrl'])
return urls
```

Comment: rest = [result['unescapedUrl'] for result in results] this worked thank you

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied you should mark the question answered. :)